# Error: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema:

> Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined

Cuando intento hacer esto:

```
for(var i=0;i<168;i++){
   for(var j=0;j<4;j++){    
      // aquí el error, Necesito obtener el name del radioBUtton de forma dinámica.   
      var a=document.forms[i].elements[j].name; 
   }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el `name` de un `radiobutton` para este caso?

Gracias.

Comment: esos números '168' y '4' de los ciclos están puestos en duro? es decir, no estas leyendo el tamaño de la lista/colección/arreglo que vas a iterar?

Comment: Podrías compartir el html para ver cómo se te puede solucionar el problema?

Comment: @Kleith pues independiente del documento html, al tener en duro un número para la cantidad de iteraciones a realizar, el potencial de errores aumenta. Si tiene 2 `form` pero piensa recorrer hasta el 168, ya con eso el código deja de funcionar a la iteración número 3 y al intentar obtener el form número 3 javascript le retorna `unndefined` porque no existe y bueno esa variable no tiene propiedades por lo que al pedirle `elements` a `undefined` aparece el error por el que está preguntando.

Comment: Como podria solucionarlo? 
atualmente tengo un table y por cada tr tengo un forms con sus td y dentro un radiobutton.